# Naming question: Note vs Comment

Tags: terminology, semantics

Working on a support ticket system and am unsure the best way to name a particular piece of functionality.

Users are able to submit any number of text entries that are attached to a single ticket for use by internal power-users. My team is trying to decide on whether to call them Comments or Notes.

For reference in case it's relevant, each set of text (note/comment) on a ticket has:

- Who made it
- When it was made

It is not:

- Editable
- Visible to end-users.

Other details:

- Tickets are rarely seen by end-users and the notes/comments will never be seen by end-users
- Notes/comments can be used for anything that isn't data based. Examples:

  - This user has been difficult in the past, caution
  - Looked into this a little but went on PTO, feel free to pick up
  - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ

### Note:

#### Pros:

- Calls out things that are *note*worthy.

#### Cons:

- Usually seen as a single, editable text field

### Comment:

#### Pros:

- Text entries are for people to *comment* on a Ticket

#### Cons:

- Insinuates a discussion is happening (that is not their intention)

Would love if anyone knows of any existing discussions or notable examples that would help make a decision as there are pros and cons of each.

Comment: Who submits the ticket? The end-user? Can any power-user enter a note/comment on a ticket? If so, why would they? Are they suggesting a solution to the ticket? Elaborating the ticket? Allocating resources? Does one of the power-users finally respond to whoever submitted the ticket?

Comment: Tickets are created automatically from some negative issue that an end-user has. End-users very rarely see tickets. Power-users want the ability to add any arbitrary information to a ticket for purpose. Anything from "this user has been difficult in the past, caution" to "haha, they used a funny word in their complaint". These comments/notes are exclusively for internal use- they are never exposed to end-users.

Comment: Relevant: [What's the difference between comment and note?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/317865/whats-the-difference-between-comment-and-note)

Answer (score 0):

Neither "Note" nor "Comment" communicate terribly well that the user won't see the thing. Being explicit (eg "private comment", "internal note", "memo to coworkers") may be useful here.

It may also not be necessary, as the danger of a screwup this way round is fairly minimal. Worst case is that a ticket will go unanswered for a little longer. It'd be worse if your operators are facing the same problem in reverse; if they want to leave a private comment on something that turns out to be actually public, they can really embarrass the company.